# IP Address pfsense

Tags: networking, virtualbox, lubuntu

I have 2 VM  lubuntu   And  fpsense and i want connect lubuntu 1 , lubuntu 2 with pfsense

I set interface ip address in pfsense 192.168.1.5 
But does not accept this ip address , and i try set 10.10.10.1

Succeeded in contact with lubuntu 1 and lubuntu 2

Why ip address 192.168.1.5 dose not connect with lubuntu 1, lubuntu 2 ?

Answer (score 0):

which interface you try to give the ip? I think you try that with the LAN interface.

When you are trying to give the IP the IP to the LAN interface follow these steps and it should work:

1. Go to Pfsense and click Interfaces and select LAN (your internal network)
2. Fill in the IP4 setting the following IP: 192.168.1.0 and select the /24 subnet
3. Make sure that your WAN Interface Setup is right
4. Now make sure that your vm`s only connected with your LAN Interface

And it should be done.

Post please your WAN Interface Settings when its not working after these steps.